# Create VLAN to use as a single-NIC router

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, vlan

My goal is to run a software router (Sophos) in KVM, using a single physical NIC in an X220T for the WAN-side, LAN-side, host (Kubuntu), and any other KVM guests.

I tried following https://wiki.ubuntu.com/vlan, but it seems outdated using `/etc/network/interfaces`. For now, these are the commands that seem to do stuff:

```
sudo apt-get install VLAN
sudo modprobe 8021q
sudo su -c 'echo "8021q" >> /etc/modules'

sudo vconfig add enp0s25 444
sudo vconfig add enp0s25 888
sudo ip link set up enp0s25.444
sudo ip link set up enp0s25.888
```

The switch setup is VLAN 444 for WAN, VLAN 888 for LAN:

- Port 1 - Modem, member of VLAN 444, ingress `pvid` 444, untagged egress.
- Port 2 - This X220T, member of VLAN 444 and 888, ingress `pvid` 888 (My understanding is this only applies to untagged packets i.e. from the non-VLAN interface, but packets already tagged 444 will remain 444, even with pvid set to 888), tagged egress for both VLAN 444 and 888.
- Ports 3-8 - Client workstations, members of VLAN 888, ingress pvid 888, untagged egress.

I was able to use `virt` manager to give Sophos both VLAN interfaces (444 passthrough, 888 bridge so it will share with host and other `vguests`), but in the ISO installer, I didn't know which was which between `eth0` and `eth1` so I guessed eth0 for WAN and eth1 for LAN and switched the cables around to try both sides, but I couldn't access the management address in either case.

Since it's not working, for now, I've plugged the X220T back into the old router so I can at least SSH into it... here is the output of `ip addr` at this point, maybe I have a wrong setting somewhere?

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:de:f1:61:23:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.22/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s25
       valid_lft 245314sec preferred_lft 245314sec
    inet6 fe80::39be:9737:c950:363f/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:88:b4:5f:53:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:09:fd:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:09:fd:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
12: enp0s25.444@enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:de:f1:61:23:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::f2de:f1ff:fe61:23ac/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: enp0s25.888@enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:de:f1:61:23:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::f2de:f1ff:fe61:23ac/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: can you add output of `bridge link show`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All it is needed to configure vlan with iproute2 is as below:

```
ip link add name ${VLAN interface name} link ${parent interface name} type vlan id ${tag}
```

`"VLAN interface name"` - any name;
`"parent interface name"` - trunk interface;
`"tag"` - 802.1q vlan id